# Golang: How to build deterministic in github ci actions and local on m1 mac

Tags: go, build, x86-64, apple-m1, deterministic

I am trying to build deterministic go executables. My build script is really simple:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

BASEPATH=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
cd "$BASEPATH/lambda"
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 GOFLAGS="-trimpath" GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct go build
ls -la cdk-sops-secrets
touch -t 202002020000 cdk-sops-secrets
chmod 755 cdk-sops-secrets
shasum cdk-sops-secrets
ls -la cdk-sops-secrets
```

this runs fine, but produces different binarys/executables on my m1 mac and in the github actions run. They differ in size and shasum. Even if I use the same docker image (apart from that one is arm and the other is amd64).

Is it possible to build a shasum / byte-by-byte identical version of my code?

Comment: your code binary would depend on the architecture on which it is meant to run.

Comment: yes - and on both environments I build for linux/amd64

Comment: Check if the compiler versions match

Comment: Yep, they match :-/

Answer (score 0):

This script builds the same versions in CI and locally

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "GOROOT: $GOROOT / GOPATH: $GOPATH"
BASEPATH=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
cd "$BASEPATH/lambda"
export GOOS=linux 
export GOARCH=amd64
export GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
export CGO_ENABLED=0
go build -trimpath -buildvcs=false -ldflags="-s -w -buildid="
ls -la cdk-sops-secrets
shasum cdk-sops-secrets
touch -t 202002020000 cdk-sops-secrets
chmod 755 cdk-sops-secrets
ls -la cdk-sops-secrets
shasum cdk-sops-secrets
```